# Scala and HttpClient: How do I resolve this error?

Tags: scala, httpclient

I'm using scala with Apache HttpClient, and working through examples.  I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/name/IdeaProjects/JakartaCapOne/src/JakExamp.scala
   Error:Error:line (16)error: overloaded method value execute with alternatives 
(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest)org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
<and> 
(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)org.apache.http.HttpResponse
 cannot be applied to 
(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler[String])
val responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler)
```

Here is the code with the error and line in question highlighted:

```
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient


object JakExamp {
 def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
   val httpclient: HttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient
   val httpget: HttpGet = new HttpGet("www.google.com")

   println("executing request..." + httpget.getURI)
   val responseHandler: ResponseHandler[String] = new BasicResponseHandler
   val responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler)
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   println(responseBody)

   client.getConnectionManager.shutdown

 }
}
```

I can successfully run the example in java...

Comment: Please put code and error in the question itself.

Comment: I apologize Daniel... I will add it to the question.

Comment: I must apologize again... I will post code/error in question from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Ive had to deal with this as well. Try something like the following:

```
val handler:ResponseHandler[String] = new BasicResponseHandler
val request = new HttpGet("...")
val response = client execute request
val body = handler handleResponse response
```

This works fine for me in 2.7.7. Its only 1 extra line, so not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

For Scala 2.7 it was reported ([2016](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2016)) but with little success. Maybe one can reopen it giving a case wich is easier to reproduce.

You can use reflection (via Scala's structural typing) to workaround this, as follows:

```
import org.apache.http.client._
import org.apache.http.client.methods._
import org.apache.http.impl.client._
val httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient
val httpget = new HttpGet("www.google.com")
val brh = new BasicResponseHandler[String]
//httpclient.execute (httpget, brh)
httpclient.asInstanceOf[{
  def execute (request: HttpUriRequest,
               responseHandler: ResponseHandler[String]): String
}].execute (httpget, brh)
```

With Scala 2.8 I have found that the following code works:

```
import org.apache.http.client._
import org.apache.http.client.methods._
import org.apache.http.impl.client._
val httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient
val httpget = new HttpGet("www.google.com")
val brh = new BasicResponseHandler
httpclient.execute (httpget, brh)
```

Therefore I think it is fixed in 2.8.

Comment: This worked as well... Good to know its fixed in 2.8.  Thank you.